# how to make a table or port data to Excel

Tags: pine-script

Is there a print or write statement in Pine Script to write in data as I parse a time line.

This is the scenario I would like to accomplish: go through each tick for the past year and if an indicator is at a certain level, write down the price of the stock at that point, together with time and date and where the MA is at that point as well as the value of some other indicators I use.

This would require the creation of a table for the data.

Failing that is it possible to send data like this to an Excel sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no tick information on the historical bars, only `OHLC`.

You can create a [table](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Tables.html) starting from v4.

```
//@version=4
study("ATR", "", true)
// We use `var` to only initialize the table on the first bar.
var table atrDisplay = table.new(position.top_right, 1, 1)
// We call `atr()` outside the `if` block so it executes on each bar.
myAtr = atr(14)
if barstate.islast
    // We only populate the table on the last bar.
    table.cell(atrDisplay, 0, 0, tostring(myAtr))
```

Comment: If there is no info on historical bars other than OHLC, then that answers my question, thank you vitruvius.